# Pop-up content sometimes appearing behind main content

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, forms, popup

On a WordPress website I have a button set up on the top right of the screen ("Request a demo") so when clicked a popup appears with some text and a HubSpot form. I have it working fine but for whatever reason about one out of ten page reloads the content of the HubSpot form won't appear in the popup but appears behind the main content on the web page by default without the button being clicked.

It's particularly bad on Firefox though where it seems to happen about 50% of the time. I'm really struggling to find a solution to this.

Website URL: http://crowdsight.co/

Comment: Try giving pop container a higher `z-index`

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle, so that we can understand the problem better

Answer (score 0):

Haven't succeeded in reproducing your problem yet but it sounds like the js hiding the form and attaching click event to the "request a demo" failed its job. Probably because it can't find the elements in the dom(the form and the "request a demo"). Make sure the form and the button's initialization happens after the dom is ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //initialization here
});
```

or:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //initialization here
});//unlike the jQuery function, this only works for modern browsers.
```

If the above fails, you can try(though this doesn't make much sense if the above fails):

```
window.onload = function() {
    //initialization here
    //here we wait for all the resources to be retrieved before we go, while
    //the above approaches only waits for the dom
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with mine the other day.  In the CSS sheet where you style the button add the following line:

```
zindex: 1;
```

In context it would look something like this:

```
.button {
   margin: 2px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   zindex: 1;
}
```