# Inline chat window opens behind website text

Tags: javascript

I've done a few searches, and I think I found the answer here: [Pop-up content sometimes appearing behind main content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098041/pop-up-content-sometimes-appearing-behind-main-content), but I don't know how to implement any of the solutions into my code (which is from a third party application). I've asked them but their support isn't the greatest. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/InstantChat/InstantChat.aspx"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadInstantChat(){
        var ICLoader = new RescueInstantChatLoader();
        ICLoader.ICContainer = "ICContainer";
        ICLoader.HostedCSS = "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/InstantChat/Standard/InstantChat.css";
        ICLoader.HostedLanguagesForChatOnlyMode = 
"https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/InstantChat/LanguagesForChatOnlyMode.js";
        ICLoader.HostedLanguagesForAppletMode = 
"https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/InstantChat/LanguagesForAppletMode.js";
        ICLoader.EntryID = "deleted for public view";
        ICLoader.Name = document.getElementById("Name").value; /* optional */
        ICLoader.Tracking0 = ""; /* optional */
        ICLoader.Language = ""; /* optional */
        ICLoader.PostMessageTargetOrigin = ""; /* optional (For implementation details, see the 
LogMeIn Rescue Customization and Integration Guide) */
        ICLoader.HostedErrorHandler = function(ErrorName){} /* optional */
        ICLoader.Start();}
    function handleRebootOrRefresh(){
        if ((window.location + "").indexOf("rescuewebsessionid") != -1) 
{document.getElementById("ICContainer").style.display=""; loadInstantChat();} /* optional */
        if (window.location.hash.length == webSessionIdLength + 1) 
{document.getElementById("ICContainer").style.display=""; loadInstantChat();} /* optional */
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="handleRebootOrRefresh();">
<table>
    <tr><td>Please enter your name: </td><td><input id="Name" type="text" maxlength="64" /></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Channel 01 - Instant Chat Configuration" 
onclick="document.getElementById('ICContainer').style.display=''; loadInstantChat();" />
<div id="ICContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 400px; height: 500px; 
display: none"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you played with `z-index` of `<div id="ICContainer">`?

Comment: Lol, I forgot to put the dash in z-index...Thanks!